mouth rig won't work – disconnected from body rig, bone groups not showing
I am trying to create a rig to move the mouth and eyes of a cartoon bear but I have encountered some issues. For context, I have created these rigs separately from the body rig... I've already animated the walk cycle and other things so I am not sure if the animations will be affected if I update the rig and assigned vertices at this stage.

New bone groups don't show when assigning vertices – So I've created the bones for the mouth rig, but when I click on the mouth on edit mode (after parenting it to the rig) the bones will not show. Sometimes it works and I am able to assign the vertices to the bones correctly but I have to redo it again due to the following issue:

Since I have created the rigs separately, I am not sure how to make it so that the mouth rig and body rig will work together. Do I parent the mouth rig to the head or the body rig? I have tried parenting them to the main rig before, but there was another issue where the head was completely deformed....
Please give me tips on how I can solve this problem and make sure that I have a working rig for the mouth and eyes which will not deform the rig and will let the updated bone groups show up in the vertices area.

Join (Ctrl J) the mouth mesh to the body mesh and also the mouth armature to the body armature, but make sure that the bones of the mouth armature have different names
